# Translations of standard fields via change set

Tags: sandbox, change-set, translation

Is it possible to migrate the translated values for standard fields and managed packages? Due to the fact that standard fields cannot be included in the change set, i can't find a way to migrate the translations of those fields. Any ideas ?